# maximum points of the string by pattern matching, algorithm problem

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, max, matching

There are a vector of skills list and a vector of points of each skill. The problem is to calculate maximum points of a string. The points of the string is sum of the points of matched skills.
Let's say skills list is {a, ab, abd, cd} and points of each skill is {1, 5, 2 ,3} and given string is "abdecdab".
Then, maximum points is ab(matched) + d(unmatched) + e(unmatched) + cd(matched) + ab(matched) = 5 + 0 + 0 + 3 + 5 = 13.
It can be also matched as abd(matched) + e(unmatched) +c(unmatched) +  d(unmatched) + ab(matched)
or
abd(matched) + e(unmatched) +c(unmatched) +  d(unmatched) + a(matched) + b(matched)
but don't result in maximum point.
I thinks it is dynamic programming problem. How to calculate maximum point of given string?

Comment: Yes! Dynamic programming sounds great for this problem. Try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.score = 0

class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

    def insert(self, word, score):
        node = self.root
        for char in word:
            node = node.children[char]
        node.score = score

def solution(skills, scores, pressed):
    dp = list(range(len(pressed),0,-1))
    print(dp)
    trie = Trie()
    for skill, score in zip(skills, scores):
        trie.insert(skill, score)
    for i in range(len(dp)-1,-1,-1):#7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
        if i < len(dp)-1:
            dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[i + 1] + 1)
        node = trie.root
        for j in range(i, len(dp)):
            if pressed[j] not in node.children:
                break
            node = node.children[pressed[j]]
            if node.score:
                if j < len(dp)-1:
                    dp[i] = max(dp[i], node.score + dp[j + 1])
                else:
                    dp[i] = max(dp[i], node.score)

    return dp[0]

skills=["a","ab","abd","cd"]
scores=[1,5,2,3]
pressed="abdecdab"

print(solution(skills,scores,pressed))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).